# Visual Studio does not show my bower_components file in solution explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio 2015 RC and Web Essentials 2015 RC. I created an Apache Cordova solution, and decied to try out Bower and Grunt on it. I right clicked the project -> add -> Grunt and Bower to Project.

[image: Grunt and Bower]

After that, I edit my `bower.json` file to add Bootstrap to my project, and Bower installs it. After it installed, I found no `bower_components` folder in my solution, so I checked the file explorer. It's there:

[image: It's there]

But not in the Solution Explorer:

[image: But not here]

How can I get `bower_components` to show up in the Solution Explorer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you click the *Show All Files* button in the Solution Explorer toolbar, the *bower_components* folder should show up.

[image: Show all files]

Comment: It might be desirable to add the folder to the project: Right click on the folder and choose "Include in Project"